# Controlling fan speed on lenovo yoga 2.13 with linux mint

Tags: linux

I am trying to fix the problem of controlling fan speed. (The fan are too loud and are running almost always unnecessarily) I followed this manual: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed     but I face the following problem. After the first step:
    `sudo sensors-detect`
The /etc/modules file contain this

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

lp
rtc

# Generated by sensors-detect on Sun Jul  5 22:45:57 2015
# Chip drivers
coretemp

# Generated by sensors-detect on Sun Jul  5 23:21:04 2015 
# Chip drivers
coretemp

# Generated by sensors-detect on Sun Jul  5 23:32:50 2015
# Chip drivers
coretemp
# I2C adapter drivers
i2c-viapro
i2c-isa
# I2C chip drivers
eeprom
it87

# Generated by sensors-detect on Sat Apr 16 11:49:27 2016
# Chip drivers
coretemp
cpuid
i2c-dev
```

In the next step: `sudo service module-init-tools restart`
I get this fail:
`module-init-tools: unrecognized service`
Does it means, that there is not sensor available to control fan speed? Is it possible to fix it somehow? I heave the following platform: `Linux Vlad-Lenovo 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`  The fan noise really makes me crazy. Could you help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance